# Apache 2 and phpmyadmin on VirtualHost on custom port: you don't have permissions to access /phpmyadmin on this server

Tags: debian, virtualhost, port, apache-2.4

I googled a lot but I did not find a guide to set up phpmyadmin on a virtualHost on a custom port.

Apache 2.4, this is my httpd-vhosts.conf

```
Listen 0.0.0.0:66

<VirtualHost *:66>
Alias /phpmyadmin /usr/local/apache2/phpmyadmin
<Directory "/usr/local/apache2/phpmyadmin">
    Options FollowSymLinks
    DirectoryIndex index.php

    <IfModule mod_php5.c>
        AddType application/x-httpd-php .php

        php_flag magic_quotes_gpc Off
        php_flag track_vars On
        php_flag register_globals Off
        php_value include_path .
    </IfModule>

</Directory>
# Authorize for setup
<Directory /usr/share/phpmyadmin/setup>
 <IfModule mod_authn_file.c>
 AuthType Basic
 AuthName "phpMyAdmin Setup"
 AuthUserFile /etc/phpmyadmin/htpasswd.setup
 </IfModule>
 Require valid-user
</Directory>
#Disallow web access to directories that don't need it
<Directory /usr/share/phpmyadmin/libraries>
   Order Deny,Allow
   Deny from All
</Directory>
<Directory /usr/share/phpmyadmin/setup/lib>
  Order Deny,Allow
  Deny from All
```

And this is the error in the logs

```
 [Thu Jul 05 17:45:49.322954 2012] [authz_core:error] [pid 14314:tid 139825756501760] [client 127.0.0.1:49262] AH01630: client denied by server configuration: /usr/local/apache2/phpmyadmin/
```

And these are the privileges

```
/usr/local/apache2# ls -l
insgesamt 60
drwxr-sr-x  2 root staff  4096  6. Jun 18:40 bin
drwxr-sr-x  2 root staff  4096  6. Jun 18:40 build
drwxr-sr-x  2 root staff  4096  6. Jun 18:40 cgi-bin
drwxr-sr-x  4 root staff  4096  5. Jul 17:04 conf
drwxr-sr-x  3 root staff  4096  6. Jun 18:40 error
drwxr-xr-x  2 root staff  4096  5. Jul 17:03 htdocs
drwxr-sr-x  3 root staff  4096  6. Jun 18:40 icons
drwxr-sr-x  2 root staff  4096  6. Jun 18:40 include
drwxr-sr-x  2 root staff  4096  5. Jul 17:44 logs
drwxr-sr-x  4 root staff  4096  6. Jun 18:40 man
drwxr-xr-x 14 root staff 12288  6. Jun 17:55 manual
drwxr-sr-x  2 root staff  4096 24. Jun 18:03 modules
drwxr-sr-x  8 root staff  4096  5. Jul 17:42 phpmyadmin
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not an Apache expert but in your `/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf` have you tried adding the following?

```
<Directory "/usr/local/apache2/phpmyadmin/">
Options All
AllowOverride All
Require all granted
</Directory>
```

There is a new permission model in Apache2 where the following is default:

```
<Directory />
    AllowOverride none
    Require all denied
</Directory>
```

So you have to specifically add exceptions for your directories. You can read more about it [here](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/upgrading.html#access)

Comment: Ah, I didnt know that... However I tried just the "AllowOverride All", not the other one, this afternoon I will give it a try, thanks for the link, it looks interesting :)

Comment: Cool, it worked like a charm, I just needed also to open the port itself on the firewall and it went. Thanks Nic :)

Comment: @elect I am glad it worked out.